# Simple Select Sql statement returns empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and I am trying to get all of the data(for now) from a table in the database.

```
include_once("dbconnect.php");  
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM  temperature");

while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    print_r($row);
    echo $row;

}
```

dbconnect.php - This is used in other scripts and works well, but just in case :

```
$hostname = 'localhost';

$username = 'root';

$password = '123456';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=arduinotest", $username, $password);
```

Neither `print_r($row);` or `echo ($row);` displays anything

What am I missing ?

Table name is correct, have also tried dbname.tablename.

EDIT : When `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` is used it outputs `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: is the table empty? if not, what is the error message?

Comment: table is not empty, and there is no error message, just blank page. if i use print_r($dbh->errorInfo()); it outputs Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `$stmt->execute()` missing.

Thanks to  Sebas for noticing